# Send data between content-script/background

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

This is my current project:

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "name": "Sample Commands Extension",
  "description": "Press Ctrl+Shift+U to send an event (Command+Shift+U on a Mac).",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/commands",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "commands": {
    "toggle-feature": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+Shift+U" },
      "description": "Send a 'toggle-feature' event to the extension"
    }
  }
}
```

**background.js**:

```
    /**
     * Returns all of the registered extension commands for this extension
     * and their shortcut (if active).
     *
     * Since there is only one registered command in this sample extension,
     * the returned `commandsArray` will look like the following:
     *    [{
     *       name: "toggle-feature",
     *       description: "Send a 'toggle-feature' event to the extension"
     *       shortcut: "Ctrl+Shift+U"
     *    }]
     */
    var gettingAllCommands = browser.commands.getAll();
    gettingAllCommands.then((commands) => {
      for (command of commands) {
        console.log(command);
      }
    });

    /**
     * Fired when a registered command is activated using a keyboard shortcut.
     *
     * In this sample extension, there is only one registered command: "Ctrl+Shift+U".
     * On Mac, this command will automatically be converted to "Command+Shift+U".
     */
    browser.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
      console.log("onCommand event received for message: ", command);
      // send to core.js the command?
    });
```

**core.js**:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(request => {
  alert(request.greeting);
});
```

it works with my keyboard shortcut, I get that message I'm logging. My question is: how can I send the command to the `core.js`, and how can I make it work just with the active current tab one, and not with all the opened ones? The files are on the same folder.

Comment: You appear to have copied content from a different post on a Stack Exchange site. The [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license (used for all posts on Stack Exchange) requires that you provide attribution for anything (e.g. text/code/images/etc.) which you copy from a Stack Exchange site. Using Stack Exchange content is *fine*, but attribution is required when you do. You have not provided attribution. Please [edit] this post to include attribution of the content which you have copied. [Note: I am reverting the edit for another reason. This is FYI for the future.]

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating an Answer, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users should proactively revert such changes. I have done/will do so here. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but it needs to be a new Question.

Comment: @Makyen I actually copied the code from https://developer.mozilla.org/, not from here.

Comment: If you solved the issue about which this Question was written yourself, with different code, you should post an Answer with that solution and accept that Answer.  When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a message from the background script to content scripts in a tab by using [`tabs.sendMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage) ([Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage)), to which you must provide the tab ID of the tab you wish to receive the message. You can not broadcast a message to all tabs with one API call. To send to only the tab that is the active tab in the current window, you first have to find out which tab that is. You can do that with [`tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query) ([Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)).

The code below will send a message to the content script in the current tab. The callback version works in either Firefox or Chrome, the Promises version only works in Firefox (Chrome doe not implement `browser.*`).

### Using callbacks (`chrome.*`, can use in Chrome or Firefox):

```js
/*                   Callback based version (chrome.*)
 * Send a message to the current tab. Arguments are the same as chrome.tabs.sendMessage(),
 *   except no tabId is provided.
 *
 * sendMessageToCurrentTab(
 *     message (any) message to send
 *     options (optional object) same as tabs.sendMessage():'frameId' prop is the frame ID.
 *     callback (optional callback for response)
 * )
 */
function sendMessageToCurrentTab(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //Get arguments as an array
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
        args.unshift(tabs[0].id); //Add tab ID to be the new first argument.
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage.apply(this,args);
    });
}
```

### Using Promises (`browser.*`, can use in Firefox):

```js
/*                  Promises based version (browser.*)
 * Send a message to the current tab. Arguments are the same as browser.tabs.sendMessage(),
 *   except no tabId is provided.
 *
 * sendMessageToCurrentTab(
 *     message (any) message to send
 *     options (optional object) same as tabs.sendMessage():'frameId' prop is the frame ID.
 * )
 */
function sendMessageToCurrentTab(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //Get arguments as an array
    return browser.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}).then(function(tabs){
        args.unshift(tabs[0].id); //Add tab ID to be the new first argument.
        return browser.tabs.sendMessage.apply(this,args);
    });
}
```

### Need to inject the content script first

However, prior to being able to send a message to a content script, the content script needs to be injected in the page. You will need to inject the content script by either using a [`content_scripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) entry in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json) or using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript). For example, you could inject the script and send the message (after the script is injected) using:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file:'core.js'
}, function(){
    sendMessageToCurrentTab("test");
});
```

Comment: could you please show how to implement it in my case on my background.js? I'm getting errors such as `Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: That error indicates that the [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts) has not been injected into the tab. You will need to inject the content script by either using a `content_scripts` entry in your *manifest.json* or [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript). For example, you could inject the script and send the message (after the script is injected) using `chrome.tabs.executeScript({file:'core.js'}, function(){sendMessageToCurrentTab("test");});`

Comment: @CallumBuntine, I edited this Answer to include the *brief* information on how to inject a content script which I had provided as a comment here.

Comment: I've re-edited the OP. I'm still getting that error including one called `Unchecked lastError value: Error: No window matching {"matchesHost":[]}`

Comment: Solved myself, sorry for the inconvenience.